# Inserting Superscript Numbers in MS SQL

Tags: sql, insert, varchar, superscript

Trying to insert a value into a `varchar` data field with the Superscript number of 4 (power of 4) at the end.

I'm able to insert/update values using superscript 2 and 3 (ie squared and cubed), but I can't get the power of 4 to enter correctly into a `varchar` field?

It does work if I switch the field to a `nvarchar`, but I'm trying to avoid that.

This works for squared or to the power of 2

```
update mytable
set myfield = 'test'+NCHAR(0xb2)
```

However, trying to get this to work using a 4 at the end...

```
update mytable
set myfield = 'test'+NCHAR(0x2074)
```

It just updates it a numeric 4 and not superscript 4. Is this because the `VarChar` datatype recognizes squared and cubed, but not any other ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superscripts beyond 3 are only available as Unicode characters, so you need to use an `NVARCHAR` instead of a `VARCHAR` for your data field, unfortunately.

Please see the [ASCII table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/) for allowable characters without using `NVARCHAR` - You'll only see superscripts for 2 and 3.