# Excel import with superscript PHP

Tags: php, ios, excel, cakephp, superscript

Can import the data from Excel file easily. But while importing the data the Superscript,it cannot be fetched in the same format from the Excel file.

While importing n<sup>2</sup> from the file it appears as n2, Similarly for the other superscript variables too.

I have used PHPExcel to import the excel file, Using the following code `$cell->getValue()->getRichTextElements();` 
can add the `<sup>` before and `</sup>` after the superscript text and save it in DB.

Above method will appear properly for the WEB, I also have the iOS app, when I send the data to iOS, the `<sup>` and `</sup>` is also shown along with the text.

Is there a way to solve it, with out adding the superscript tag for WEB, so that it appears properly in iOS.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: of course it'll render in "web" - you're displaying html in a web browser. it'll get rendered. unless you tell ios it's display html, it'll treat html tags as any other text...

Comment: @MarcB, the app i am creating is not the hybrid app, it's a native one. So i cannot display text as html in it.

Answer (score 1):

In your given case, the superscript is stored as HTML `n<sup>2</sup>`. Hence it will display correctly on a web page. (Because it is rendering HTML `n<sup>2</sup>`. If however, you are rendering it in iOS app, then it will only show the text `n<sup>2</sup>`, because that's the actually value stored in the database.

You can render this string/text as HTML in you iOS native app, here is a question here: [How to show an HTML string on a UILabel in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946251/how-to-show-an-html-string-on-a-uilabel-in-ios)

Or, you can store the original value in the db as some unicode (nchar, nvarchar type) to store the subscript notation.
Here is a question relating to that: [Inserting Superscript Numbers in MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884018/inserting-superscript-numbers-in-ms-sql)